# Seekbar progressdrawable not work correctly below Android M

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-seekbar, layer-list

I have a seekbar whose height is `16dp`.

```
minHeight="16dp"
maxHeight="16dp"
```

Now I have to use custom progress drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="xxx"/>
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="xxx"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="xxx"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

As you see, I use `left`,`top`,`right`,`bottom` to insert `progress` and `secondaryProgress`.

**It works well above Android M**,however below Android M,the porgress and secondaryProgress fills the `background` in other word the `background` item is covered by `progress` and `secondaryProgress`.**But I want progress and secondaryProgress smaller than background item.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution:

```
LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) mSeekBar.getProgressDrawable();
// secondaryProgress
drawable.setLayerInset(1, padding, padding, padding, padding);
// progress
drawable.setLayerInset(2, padding, padding, padding, padding);
```

Can anyone explain why it's useless to set `left` `right` `top` `bottom` in xml below API 23?